# Remove subtotal and Shipping calculator block in Woocommerce cart totals section

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, cart

In woocommerce, I am using the following to remove the shipping block in cart totals section bloc:

```
 function disable_shipping_calc_on_cart( $show_shipping ) {
        if( is_cart() ) {
            return false;
        }
        return $show_shipping;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_ready_to_calc_shipping', 'disable_shipping_calc_on_cart', 99 );
```

But in that cart totals section bloc there are some other things like the cart **Subtotal** and **Total**.

I just need to keep only **Total**

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Not clear what you are exactly looking for....if you are looking for removing shipping section,- you can do it from woocommerce settings under shipping section - > shippings options


But if you are looking for removing that 'subtotal' text, unfortunately there is no such hook to do that, you have to modify your theme according to that.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to keep only the total on cart totals section. For that the only way is overriding woocommerce templates.

There is 2 steps:

1. You should read [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) to understand how you can override woocommerce templates via your active child theme (or active theme).
   So you will have to create in you active theme folder (if it doesn't exist yet) a folder named "woocommerce" and a sub-sub folder "cart"…
   You will have to copy from the `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-totals.php` to your active theme `woocommerce/cart/cart-totals.php` *(if it not exist yet)*.

---

2. Editing  `cart-totals.php`template and removing code:
   Since WooCommerce version 2.3.6 and up: You will have to remove the code from line 32 to 59 *(You will keep only fees and taxes if they are any)*
   If you want to keep only the total amount you will remove the code from line 32 to line 87 
   Then save.

> You will not need your function code anymore

**Now your cart totals will be something like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'adjust_woocommerce_get_order_item_totals' );

function adjust_woocommerce_get_order_item_totals( $totals ) {
  unset($totals['cart_subtotal']  );
  return $totals;
}
```

Is this what you are looking for? Basically you asked to remove the subtotal.

Comment: This did not work for me either. I could not find any other solution other than adding a display:none to the CSS element.